# External USB DVD Drive support

Tags: 12.04

I am planning to purchase External USB DVD writer for my desktop which has Ubuntu 14.04 version. 
Please let me know if all the External USB DVD writers are ready to use after plugged into USB port ? 
if not then which are the external USB DVD writers available which are supported by Ubuntu 14.04 release .

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem using it. The first time you insert a DVD Ubuntu should autodetect and prompt you; if not, go to **System Settings > Details > Removable media** and find your drive.